# How to export Flash builder air mobile project to swf

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flash, flex4.5

I have created a flex mobile as3 project that exports to air, to ipa and apk. 
This project does not use any specific to mobile or air calls (camera,  files. .)
my question is : how do I create a swf ?
Regards

Comment: if you have the source code you can simply create a new project with the same files and set the project's runtime to be Flash Player (instead of AIR for desktop/IOS/Android). The .air file is actually a zip file containing a main .swf file (among other files), but I doubt you will be able to simply run that. (My guess it will check it's runtime and die throwing errors missing AIR runtime classes if you run this swf in Flash Player directly).

Comment: Yes, but how to maintain 2 projects then ?

Comment: @user300675 In that case, you would create your core classes as a library/module.  And then compile against them when creating your Flash player or Adobe Air App.  That way, the main pieces of functionality stay the same, only the window dressing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your project doesn't use any AIR-specific APIs, you can use an `Ant` build to create a SWF from your mobile project.  The following build file will do the trick if your project is self-contained as a single Flash Builder project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="Build" default="build">
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" value="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0" />
    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar" />

    <property name="PROJECT_NAME" value="MyMobileProject" />
    <property name="PROJECT_BASE_DIR" value="C:/FlexProjects/${PROJECT_NAME}" />
    <property name="PATH_TO_SRC_FOLDER" value="${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src" />
    <property name="OUTPUT_DIR" value="${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/bin" />

    <target name="build">
        <mxmlc file="${PATH_TO_SRC_FOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.mxml" 
            output="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.swf" 
            show-actionscript-warnings="false" show-binding-warnings="false"
            locale="en_US" incremental="true">
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
            <source-path path-element="${PATH_TO_SRC_FOLDER}" />
            <external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs" append="true">
                <include name="*.swc" />
            </external-library-path>
            <compiler.library-path dir="${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/libs" append="true" includes="*"/> 
        </mxmlc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: can you give me more details about how to compile that ? or run that ?